# How can I support localization in windows mobile 6.5?

Tags: windows-mobile, localization, globalization

I have a simple C# app that needs to support several languages. What is the best way to do this in windows mobile 6.5? Also, how can I test the different languages? Anyone have an example?

Comment: We really need to know the language (C#, C++, VB.NET) you're writing in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Crowdin.net](https://crowdin.net)** is a good solution to perform incremental localization and support translations.

*[Disclaimer: this is my site]*